# How to set parameters in Speclow BDD test if it is not type String

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

[image]

In BDD test I have to use parameter type Astra.Package.Entities.Data.Fixture.
In the situation when I put '(.*)' in Then step, I am getting this exception:

Message:

> System.InvalidCastException : Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Astra.Package.Entities.Data.Fixture'.

How to set parameter in BDD Specflow test in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Step Argument Conversion](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Step-Argument-Conversions.html) to convert a piece of a step into a different kind of object:

```cs
[Binding]
public class Transforms
{
    [StepArgumentTransformation(@"'(.*)'")]
    public Fixture ConvertToFixture(string text)
    {
        // convert 'text' to a Fixture object
    }
}
```

SpecFlow will automatically match the type for the step argument to the return type of your step argument transformation. Your step can remain the same:

```cs
[Then(@"...")]
public void ThenIShouldSeeDataOnIPM(Fixture inlayFixture)
{
    // ...
}
```